# Unable to create hello world with LWC Open Source

Tags: lightning-web-components, open-source

I am trying to get a hello-world going with LWC (open source!!!), to run it as a stand-a-lone webpage/website.

I followed this guide: https://lwc.dev/guide/install

```
npm init lwr        # Follow the on-screen instructions
                    # Select the "Single Page App" project
                    # Select the "LWC" variant
cd YourProjectName
npm install
npm run start
```

Then went to the #WebPack section installed the webpack and packages, created the config files, added the demo app, but got the following error when I ran `npx webpack build`:

```
user@work lwr-final]$ npx webpack build
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/home/user/Projects/lwc/lwr-final/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/home/user/Projects/lwc/lwr-final/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///home/user/Projects/lwc/lwr-final/webpack.config.js:3:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

I went through the install guide a number of times with each time a fresh/clean install, but every time the same error. (Running on Fedora linux v38)

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

[Link to the source-code on GitHub](https://github.com/wimvelzeboer/lwc-boilerplate-not-working)